# Apache Airflow : Passing Data on Custom Operator

Tags: python, airflow

i have this two custom operator

```
class FetchDataOperator(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, connection, sql_commands, key, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FetchDataOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.connection = connection
        self.sql_commands = sql_commands
        self.key = key

    def execute(self, context):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(self.sql_commands)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        context['ti'].xcom_push(key=self.key, value=records)
```

```
class InsertDataOperator(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, connection, sql_commands, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InsertDataOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.connection = connection
        self.sql_commands = sql_commands
        self.data = data

    def execute(self, context):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(self.sql_commands, self.data)
        self.connection.commit()
```

im confused on how to get the data that i pushed into xcom on FetchDataOperator, into 'data' parameter in InsertDataOperator, i tried this

```
insert_data = InsertDataOperator(
    task_id="insert_data",
    connection=conn,
    sql_commands=insert_query,
    op_kwargs={
        'data' : "{{ti.xcom_pull(key='data', task_ids='fetch_data')}}"
    },
    provide_context=True
)
```

but it giving me this error

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Argument ['data'] is required
```

is there any way to do it correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor of `InsertDataOperator` has signature:

```
__init__(self, connection, sql_commands, data, *args, **kwargs)
```

So obviously `data` should be passed as its a required argument.

Change your constructor call to:

```
insert_data = InsertDataOperator(
    task_id="insert_data",
    connection=conn,
    sql_commands=insert_query,
    data="{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='data', task_ids='fetch_data') }}"
)
```